# (iOS) If an image is downscaled does it use less ram?

Tags: ios, uiimage

If I have a 200x200 UImageView and I provide an 1000x1000 image, and the image gets downscaled. Does it use 1000x1000x4 bytes of ram? or does it use the downscaled dimensions x 4?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the original image data loaded from the PNG, then it consumes W x H x 4 bytes. Note that under iOS, a 2x image would actually be (W x 2) x (H x 2) x 4 since on a 2x scale device the points are less than actual pixels. Scaling an image down to a smaller size does save a lot of memory, but you have to explicitly allocate a graphic context and render the smaller image before using the new smaller context to create a new CGImgRef and UIImage.